# Одинаковый внешний вид приложения на разных версиях андроида

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, activity, android-themes

Есть приложение на андроид которое разрабатывалось с учетом версии 4.0, то есть вид элементов в activity_main и в остальных частях приложения. Но при запуске на другой версии например 7.0 все виджеты выглядят не так как задумывалось иначе. Для решения этой проблемы нужно создавать свою тему или как то по другому можно решить данный вопрос. Возможно я не сильно понятно объяснил свой вопрос если что отвечу на любые вопросы. Буду благодарен за любую помощь или ценные советы.

Comment: Вообще рекомендуется под каждую версию соответствующий стиль использовать.

Comment: используйте библиотеку поддержки AppCompat и на всех версиях будет стиль Material

Comment: Вообще-то стиль у Вас и должен быть одинаковым, если в ресурсах не заданы разные темы для разных API. Одно время студия создавала новые проекты именно с такой конфигурацией - проверьте свои файлы стилей.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно изучить [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html), [примеры](https://dzone.com/articles/android-material-themes-made-easy-with-appcompat)

Answer (score 0):

Какой Layout используете в разметке? Разные Layout-ы по разному себя ведут со сменой разрешения или размера экрана. Вот первое, что попалось на эту тему: https://ru-code-android.livejournal.com/4327.html

Comment: часть линеар а часть релатив

Comment: причем же здесь тема, используемая для оформления виджетов в приложении?